# Obtaining a parallel Stream from a Collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it correct that with Java 8 you need to execute the following code to *surely* obtain a parallel stream from a `Collection`?

```
private <E> void process(final Collection<E> collection) {
    Stream<E> stream = collection.parallelStream().parallel();
    //processing
}
```

From the `Collection` API:

> default Stream parallelStream()
>
> Returns a possibly parallel Stream with this collection as its source. It is allowable for this method to return a sequential stream.

From the `BaseStream` API:

> S parallel()
>
> Returns an equivalent stream that is parallel. May return itself, either because the stream was already parallel, or because the underlying stream state was modified to be parallel.

Is it not awkward that I need to call a function that supposedly parallellizes the stream twice?

Comment: Not all _collections_ and _stream_ support parallel execution, but all collections and streams have these. I think that's the reason for the weird documentation. So. no. You don't have to invoke both methods.

Comment: @nosid However if this method is invoked a collection that does not support parallelism, then `parallelStream()` will return a sequential stream, but the contract of `parallel()` guarantees that the stream *will* be parallel. That would lead to that I need to invoke both methods?

Answer (score 3):

Basically the default implementation of `Collection.parallelStream()` does create a parallel stream. The implementation looks like this:

```
default Stream<E> parallelStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), true);
}
```

But this being a default method, it is perfectly valid for some implementing class to provide a different implementation to create a *sequential* stream too. For example, suppose I create a `SequentialArrayList`:

```
class MySequentialArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public Stream<String> parallelStream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }
}
```

For an object of that class, the following code will print `false` as expected:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new MySequentialArrayList();
System.out.println(arrayList.parallelStream().isParallel());
```

In this case invoking `BaseStream#parallel()` method ensures that the stream returned is always parallel. Either it was already parallel, or it makes it parallel, by setting the `parallel` field to `true`:

```
public final S parallel() {
    sourceStage.parallel = true;
    return (S) this;
}
```

This is the implementation of `AbstractPipeline#parallel()` method.

So the following code for the same object will print `true`:

```
System.out.println(arrayList.parallelStream().parallel().isParallel());
```

But if the stream is already parallel, then yes it is an extra method invocation, but that will ensure you always get a parallel stream. I've not yet digged much into the parallelization of streams, so I can't comment on what kind of Collection or in what cases would `parallelStream()` give you a sequential stream though.