# Why does the StreamSupport.stream() method have a parallel parameter?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Looking at the method `StreamSupport#stream(Spliterator, boolean)` and similar methods for primitive streams. If the `boolean` parameter is true you get a parallel stream.

Why does this method need that parameter, when you can make a stream parallel by invoking `Stream#parallel()`?

I.e. is `StreamSupport.stream(mySpliterator, true);` different in any way to `StreamSupport.stream(mySpliterator, false).parallel();` ?

Comment: Looking at `AbstractPipeline` as an implementation of `BaseStream`, both of them eventually seem to update the `parallel`ism to `true`.

Comment: I guess that the key might lay in what the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html says (emphasis by me): "**Low-level utility** methods for creating and manipulating streams.
This class is **mostly for library writers** presenting stream views of data structures; most static stream **methods intended for end users are in the various Stream classes**."

Comment: The answer might be similar to [why we can call `parallelStream()` on a `Collection`, instead of `stream().parallel()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603187/2711488). If we want to call it an answer (rather than a big complicated picture).

Comment: @Holger yep that's what I was looking for.. I suppose my question is a duplicate of that one